# Do any of the color bands in a rainbow contain an electrical charge relative to clouds that might explain a photo of lightning striking a rainbow?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, charge, refraction

Caveat: While I am not a physicist myself, I am extremely interested in physical phenomena. I am well versed in electrical theory, and I am aware of the attraction between the bottoms of clouds and the ground.
However, when I saw the photo of lightning apparently striking a rainbow, I could not come up with a strictly electrical explanation.

Comment: Rainbow is not a material object (it's not even located at the place you think it is, e.g. it shifts together with the observer, like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8BQ2YJRk3Y)). The fact that a lightning overlaps a rainbow doesn't mean anything at all.

Comment: @Ruslan, to post a brief answer, please post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that picture too. the lightning strike was a coincidence; there's nothing in a rainbow that would draw lightning.

Note also that what we perceive as a rainbow is not an arc in space but a cone in space with its tip centered on our eye. as such, it has an extent in space spanning hundreds of meters in the direction pointing away from our eye, and if a bolt of lightning passes through the enclosed conical volume anywhere along that length, it will look like the lightning "struck" the rainbow.